# Oracle SQL Query not showing all records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables

production (serial#,batch#,productCode) 600 rows,
quality (batch#,test1,test2,test3,test4) 600 rows,
defective (defectiveID,serial#) 323 rows

batch# is linked between the production and quality tables and serial# is linked between production and defective tables.

I need to formulate a query to assign a status to each of the 600 batch#s.

The condition that needs to be met is:

Each batch that has more then one serial in the defective table needs to be labeled as poor. If it has one or less the batch quality is good.

here is what I have so far:

```
    SELECT p.batch_NO, p.PRODUCT_CODE, q.test_1, q.test_2, q.test_3, q.test_4,
    CASE WHEN count(*) <= 1 THEN 'Good'
    ELSE 'Poor'
    END AS "Batch Quality"
    FROM DEFECTIVE d, production p, quality q
    WHERE q.BATCH_NO = p.BATCH_NO
    And d.serial_NO = p.serial_NO
    GROUP BY p.batch_NO, p.PRODUCT_CODE, q.test_1, q.test_2, q.test_3, q.test_4
    order by p.batch_NO;
```

The problem is I only get 249 rows and not 600.
I should get 600 records with 61 poor and 539 good.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing an inner join between production and defective tables, only batches that have defective serial #'s will be returned.

Also, if there could be duplicate serial #'s in the defective table and you only want to count distinct serial #'s, OR if there is a one to many relationship between production and quality, then you need to count the distinct defective serial #'s instead of `count(*)`.  `Count(*)` in your example will never return a 0 because you have at least one row between the production and quality tables, even if there are 0 defective records.

I general prefer using the INNER/LEFT/RIGHT join sytax vs. TABLE1, TABLE2 format with the (+) for outer joins because it is easier for me to read.  Here is a version that should work:

```
SELECT p.batch_NO, p.PRODUCT_CODE, q.test_1, q.test_2, q.test_3, q.test_4,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT d.serial_NO) <= 1 
        THEN 'Good'
        ELSE 'Poor'
    END AS "Batch Quality"
    --additional column to help check your output
    , COUNT(DISTINCT d.serial_NO) as DefectiveSerialNoCount
FROM production p
    LEFT JOIN quality q ON q.BATCH_NO = p.BATCH_NO 
    LEFT JOIN DEFECTIVE d ON d.serial_NO = p.serial_NO
GROUP BY p.batch_NO, p.PRODUCT_CODE, q.test_1, q.test_2, q.test_3, q.test_4
ORDER BY p.batch_NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is left/right outer join for the production table..
try running

```
SELECT p.batch_NO, p.PRODUCT_CODE, q.test_1, q.test_2, q.test_3, q.test_4,
CASE WHEN count(distinct d.serial_NO) <= 1 THEN 'Good'
    ELSE 'Poor'
    END AS "Batch Quality"
    FROM DEFECTIVE d, production p, quality q
    WHERE q.BATCH_NO(+) = p.BATCH_NO
    And d.serial_NO(+) = p.serial_NO
    GROUP BY p.batch_NO, p.PRODUCT_CODE, q.test_1, q.test_2, q.test_3, q.test_4
    order by p.batch_NO;
```

or use the right right outer join (in this case) for the products that have no defects and no quality checks to appear...

(I am always mixing up the right side for the (+), you should use the "left outer join" and "right outer join" whenever you do something formally, and not just to test)

just for reference : 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#SQLRF52335

Comment: thanks evenro, now I get all 600 records but now they're all poor

Comment: Try to count all the non-null relevant values :) (I'm not on my desktop - so I can't "debug" the query now , but the thing is that now the count for each is at least 1, and you need to count only a specific situation, not all of them...) - let me know if you didn't solve it in about an hour - so I could try and debug it .

Comment: I just added there a demo of how to do the count I think you need to, but I currently can't actually realize which column it is, and make sure it does it... let me know if you have any troubles with it..

Comment: By the way - is a defect is one that have 1 record or zero? I would guess the original when count(..) should be =0 for good, and >=1 for bad.

Comment: No, more then 1 defective makes it poor. So 0 or 1 defective is still good.